# Make a Social Reader App

Tags: facebook, api

How to make an app similar to Social Reader App?

Social Reader app accesses user information and posts it to their facebook newsfeed and the wall.

This is in regard to icrease popularity for my blog. I want to make such an app which can access the user information and post it to their wall and automatically to the newsfeed when somebody reads my blog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a Social reader for my blog?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9492487/how-do-i-create-a-social-reader-for-my-blog)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add FB connection functionality on your blog , or you when you are posting the article on FB wall you can point it to a 2nd domain , where the fb iframe app will be installed and that will take care of the users authentication and then it'll redirect the user to your blog .